# MAR vs Stack Pointer, Whats the difference?

Tags: computer-architecture

So I was watching some videos on a guy "Building his own 8-bit computer", and the Memory Address Register (MAR) was attached to the SRAM. The MAR took the next Program Counter value and then looked in the SRAM for the next instruction and put it on the Instruction register. (Sidenote: Why doesn't the Program Counter just go straight into a decoder instead of the MAR which is basically another register?)

Anyways, I was looking at the ATTiny85's datasheet and noticed that the "Stack Pointer" was linked to the SRAM in the block diagram (I only understand some of the basics here so apologies if this is a really stupid question). The Program counter in this case was linked directly to the SRAM and the stack pointer pointed at the SRAM as well.

Im curious exactly how this works? Im just learning Computer Architecture so some of this stuff is out of bounds in what i've learned...but Im very interested in understand how a CPU works at the base level.

Maybe im confusing SRAM and program flash in this case though. In that case then where is the MAR?

[image: Block Diagram]

Comment: You do realize that this MAR thing is not a universal concept all CPUs must work with?

Comment: Indeed, I'm familiar with the architecture of a few MCUs and have never heard of it. It seems to be a unique concept from a single project, possibly named after the school (MAR=[MARyland](https://web.archive.org/web/20170328171842/http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Overall/mar.html))?

Comment: Computing (especially home built) has more TLAs than anything else I know of, bar business school speak.

Comment: @PlasmaHH No, especially considering I am self admitting that I am a beginner at this stuff. MAR = Memory Address Register, I mean i've seen it in computer architecture books quite a lot however. The "Concept" of it didn't personally make sense to me however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mememory Address Register and the Memory Data Register are thing that can be found in most CPU *implementations*. But they are (generally) not part of the *programmers view* of the CPU: they are not needed to decribe what the CPU does at the (external) instruction level. (But they are often visible on the micro-instruction level).

Hence you might find a MAR in a picture that describes the CPU *implementation*, but you will generally not see a MAR on a picture that is intended to describe the CPU for a *programmer*. Unfortunately, it is not always clear what the intended purpose of such a picture is.

In most (simple)  cases there are multiple sources (PC, SP, other registers, immediate address from the instruction, result of a caculation) for a memory address that must be read, and there is only one address bus from the CPU to the memory. Hence there must be some way to select one of these sources. In most cases this is done by the source putting the address on an internal bus, and the MAR latching (remembering) this address. Next the memory is accessed, which takes considereable time compared to CPU-internal operations. Because the address is latched, the internal bus is free to do other usefull things (like maybe incrementing the PC).

Answer (score 1):

The diagram you include is a highly simplified view of the architecture. It only shows the major blocks that are visible to the programmer. Features that the programmer doesn't need to know about, such as whether or not there is a separate MAR, are hidden.

Having said that, note that the stack pointer is only used for accessing a stack. Typically the stack pointer will be changed only by PUSH or POP instructions. A memory address register is more generic and might hold the address for any memory access. Whether or not the SRAM or Flash actually have an MAR depends on whether they are synchronous or asynchronous and how fast they are. If a memory access can be completed in a single clock cycle then you might not need a separate MAR.

Comment: Thanks, I guess thats why it made no sense in the 8-bit computer video build I saw. He was doing instructions on a little manual clock pulse cycle (For demo purposes) and I really didn't understand what the MAR was doing (Since it seemed to be just taking the PC and then fetching that data from the SRAM's address)

Comment: I would add CALL and RET to the list of instructions likely to affect SP.